# Can someone explain nginx conditional flags? (-f, -d, -e, etc)

Tags: nginx, configuration, conditional, flags

I'm in the process of migrating from Apache to nginx and have used http://winginx.com/en/htaccess to migrate the rewrite rules. I'm trying to understand what the translated ones mean though and I can't find any documentation on it. Here's an example:

```
if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
```

I *believe* `-f` checks if a file exists, and `-d` checks if a directory exists, but what about `-e`? And where might I find these in the documentation? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html):

- checking of a file existence with the `-f` and `!-f` operators;
- checking of a directory existence with the `-d` and `!-d` operators;
- checking of a file, directory, or symbolic link existence with the
  `-e` and `!-e` operators;
- checking for an executable file with the `-x` and `!-x` operators.

Comment: The docs don't say much beyond what you pasted, but these appear to be modeled after the UNIX/POSIX "test" utility (`man test`).

Comment: `-e` seems means `everything` that "include a file, directory, or symbolic link " which mentioned above